# How can I redirect to login page after registration in this code

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

every help me :(((. here is link to my code https://github.com/tranluongtiensi/registration_system

I want to redirect the user to login page after registration, I have tried many ways but it doesn't work. thank everyone very much

Comment: Please include a more detailed description of your problem in the question AND include the relevant code, pasted into your question.  External links to code repositories are OK as a help, but the core code required to understand your question MUST be pasted directly into the question.  This is because repositories have a habit of changing over time, thus invalidating the question as an interesting reference to those that follow.  So, questions here MUST include the relevant code to understand the question pasted right into the question and formatted as code.  Please fix your question.

Comment: I'll learn from it next time, thanks for reminding

Comment: Why not fix your current question now to make it conform to the requirements here?  You can just use the "edit" link below your question to fix it.  You are getting downvotes and close votes because your question is not proper.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, i will delete this question since i have already received the appropriate answer, the answer to the reason why i didnt upload the code here is because my code is quite long, and the uploading of the code .This causes quite a lot of errors when the code is too long and not completely in the gray block. And if I want to fix that, I have to go to each line and press the space. It take many time, If you have trick to fix it, please tell me

Comment: Just indent your code one extra level in your code editor before you paste it in.  That's what I do.  Or you can select it all and use the `{}` button in the stackoverflow editor.

Comment: oh , it appear error again. the error is " 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details". It just said more details but not said how many. I was add some line but it still doesn't change anything. haizzz

Comment: The idea is that you include the most relevant portions of your code, not your entire code.  You should be making your question as easy to understand as possible with the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `window.location.href` when you submit your signup form. So your code for `registerUser(...)` would look something like this.

```
async function registerUser(event){
      event.preventDefault()
      const username = document.getElementById('user').value
      const password = document.getElementById('password').value
      const password_confirmation = document.getElementById('password_confirmation').value
      const phone = document.getElementById('tel').value

      const result = await fetch('/register',{
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({
           username,
           password,
           password_confirmation,
           phone
         })
      }).then((res) => res.json())

      if (result.status === 'ok') {
         alert('success');
         // on a successful signup, redirect user to the login page
         window.location.href = 'LINK_TO_SIGNIN_PAGE'; // exp. http://localhost/signin.html
      }else {
        alert (result.error)
      }
    }
```

Give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a redirect here to this line [here](https://github.com/tranluongtiensi/registration_system/blob/bc8b808d7d4edeb940b932a3018e3a66bc958275/registration%20system/code%20FE/signup.html#L143)

for example :

```
window.location.href = 'login.html'
```